# Issue using Goutte filter method to crawl DOM for google links

Tags: php, laravel

I want to use Goutte for getting the first result links of a google search, in order to get the links I have to use the Goutte filter method and CSS-like selectors, I want to grab all the anchor elements which are first child of div element with class r, as you can see in image bellow all result links follow that pattern.

[image]

However, when I loop through filtered elements I get nothing, any idea why is this?

```
$terms = 'Restaurante Mustang';//$request->input('terms');
        
        $url = 'http://www.google.es/search?'.http_build_query(array('q' => $terms));
        
        // Request search results:
        $client = new Client;
        $crawler = $client->request('GET', $url);


        $links = $crawler->filter('div.r > a');

        $nodes = [];
        foreach ($links as $index => $link)
        {   
            $nodes[] = $link; 
        }
        dd($nodes);
```

Is it because my selectors are wrong?

Comment: Did you try ```dd($link)```  ?

Comment: Yes, for some reason after filtering I get the WHOLE html page, afaik that should not be the case